# How to remove the space at the bottom in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: A screenshot directly from iOS simulator]

I am a newbie Flutter developer. How do you make the beggar photo fill up to the space at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Image widget there is a property called fit in that use

```
BoxFit.cover
```

you can also add height/width as

`double.infinity`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove the button bar that stays at the bottom of your app then [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIOverlays.html) should help you

Note: this will also remove the android status bar at the top, if you just want your button bar removed `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);` this should do it